# Not displaying label 'Sales Price' on the products

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart, joomla3.4

I am working on Joomla with Virtuemart; the thing is, I did a lot of changes but I think that I turn something on and now on the Shop page is showing a label that before do not was displayed.

Version: Joomla! 3.4.0 and VirtueMart 3.0.8

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is; can you provide more information? For future reference, this SO article provides a helpful guideline for posting a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, here is a helpful guideline on what not to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: How i can remove the label that is next to the price "Sales price". Where is the configuartion to turn it of

Answer (score 0):

In VirtueMart configuration find the tab "Pricing".

Uncheck the checkbox below "Show label" for "Final salesprice".

Safe the config.